# How do I use the /sys file to control the GPIO pins

Tags: gpio, readwrite

I am using a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B v1.1. 
I have looked at the GPIO file in /sys but I don't understand how I actually turn on/ turn off GPIO ports or I set them to read in/read out, I am trying to do a project for college using my Raspberry PI and LISP but without this knowledge I am unable to do this, this is the library that is written for NewLIsp: https://github.com/gatesphere/raspi-gpio-newlisp/blob/master/raspi-gpio.lsp
Some clarification of what actually needs to be written and where it needs to be written to send out/read in values on the GPIO ports is need, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen http://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Code_Samples#sysfs.2C_part_of_the_raspbian_operating_system ? You may not need to be root to export/unexport, it depends on the way your system is set up.

Comment: Have you read any of the man files e.g. `man gpio`? Why Lisp? Is this just to make it more difficult - I though Lisp was only used with Emacs these days.

Comment: @Milliways `gpio` is an executable and calling it from another is clunky and expensive vs. using a kernel fs interface. Lisp is still used in university intro AI courses (at least where I am), and along with Haskell probably one of the most popular [functional languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). For what it's worth, it's actually ahead of Haskell on [the TIOBE index](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html), which tracks current internet references (and if you look at the long term index there, was in the top 15 overall until 5 years ago).

Comment: @goldilocks I do not want to start a language war, but AFAIK NewLisp is NOT included with Raspbian, and I have never heard of anyone using Lisp on a Pi.

Comment: I think you fired the first salvo, lol.  I've (made (my share(of lisp jokes) before)).  But since I'm a perl head, I understand what it is to be badly misunderstood, etc., occasionally by people who actually think no one uses that anymore either ("Why???"), so I was trying to save the OP the hassle of having to respond.  By my reading of the Q lisp is *a requirement* for a college project (and in any case, college is one of those places people are allowed to take an interest in esoteric things for their own sake).

Comment: WRT Raspbian, I'm sure there are 2 or 3 versions of lisp available -- technically the default image doesn't include a C++ complier either, but I haven't let that stop me.  WRT "new lisp" on the pi, hey, power to them.   I'm hoping **rust** will blossom there too, but stuff like that requires a healthy group of pioneers. @Milliways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly and simply documented in [the kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt).  I will not bother to regurgitate it here.

Note that you can't use `sudo` with `echo >` because of redirection, but that does not impact what you are trying to do.

Anecdotely I'd say using if using high level stream functions doesn't work on sys/proc nodes, use lower level methods.  I don't speak lisp so I don't know how relevant that is.

Comment: Thank you :D I'll give this a read and see where I get. I want to write my own library to easily handle the I/O of the GPIO ports, but I've been confused as to how to actually do any of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some chunks of a program that might help - the whole thing is too big

import sys

#### sys.path.insert(0, '/home/pi/pgms')

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime
from   datetime import timedelta
import os
import subprocess
import glob
import suntime

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)        ## Use board pin numbering

dirarr=["off","on"]
pinarr=[7,8,10,11,12,13]

for i in range(0,6):                         ##  Print current pin usage
    fno = GPIO.gpio_function(pinarr[i])      ##  get function number
    print ("Pin " +  str(pinarr[i]) + " usage is " +  pin_use[fno])

for i in range(0,2):
    print ("  " )

print ("Python version is  %s " % str(sys.version[0:6]))

print ("GPIO   version is  %s " % GPIO.VERSION)

print ("Board revision is  %s " % getbr()[:4])

print ("Program name is    %s " % sys.argv[0])

### print("System path is ",sys.path)

for i in range(len(pinarr)):
    GPIO.setup((pinarr[i]), GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

Comment: I appreciate the help but that's not LISP.